# Anharmonic series, find a permutation of its indices so that its sum is 0

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Could you help me solve this problem?

Find such a permutation of indices of anharmonic series ($\sum _{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} \frac{1}{n}$ ) so that after this permutation its sum equals $0$.

Comment: and what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

I will give the answer and leave it to you to supply the proof. Take 1 positive term, then 4 negative terms, then 1 positive term, then 4 negative terms, and so on. Explicitly,

$$1-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{10}-\frac{1}{12}-\frac{1}{14}-\frac{1}{16}+\frac{1}{5}\dots$$